# ReportViewer height issue. Hiding scrollbars

Tags: reporting-services, reportviewer

I'm using MSSQL 2005 Reporting Services and in this case I need to display some reports on an ASP.NET page using the ReportViewer control (I guess thats the only way, right?).

The problem is that I can't get the property `SizeToReportContent` to work. When displaying the report, I get a vertical scrollbar because the report is too large. It looks like an iframe window.
Searching on google it seems to be a bug. It can be fixed by setting `AsyncRendering` to `false` but I don't want that. I need another solution.

I was wondering if it's possible to set the height on the report element using JavaScript after the report has been loaded?

Or do you know of another solution? This is really annoying.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I was wondering if these problems were corrected in the ReportViewer shipping with VS2010 Beta 1, and if I can use that in ASP.NET 3.5 (VS2008)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the height using javascript and keep Async=true.  I use this now on the 2008 version.  Here is the code I use:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
    function doResize() {
        var viewer = document.getElementById("<%=ReportViewer1.ClientID %>");
        var htmlheight = document.documentElement.clientHeight; 
        viewer.style.height = (htmlheight - 150) + "px";
    }

    window.onresize=function resize()
    { 
        doResize();
    }
</script>

<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" BackColor="#f2f2f2" 
    InternalBorderStyle="Solid" InternalBorderColor="Gray" ProcessingMode="Remote" 
    AsyncRendering="true" Width="100%" runat="server" 
    meta:resourcekey="ReportViewer1Resource1">
    <ServerReport  />        
</rsweb:ReportViewer>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
    doResize();
</script>
```

This doesn't work on VS2010 ReportViewer, however.  I'm trying to figure out a solution for that.

Comment: Did you ever happen to find a solution for VS2010 ReportViewer?

Answer (score 1):

I can't fully recall which way to go - but you either need to change the ReportViewer from Asynch to Synch rendering.  I dealt with this about 3 years ago and think that is what we did.

Comment: But I would really like to avoid that.

Comment: The trouble is that when the report is being rendered it doesn't know how large it will be.  Until the rendering is complete it doesn't know that.  There may be a java solution that's come out since I last had to deal with this, though.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me.
Like Tommy said - it's not ideal, but if you don't know how big the report is there's little you can do. Another option would be to dynamically set the viewer height by getting the client's browser window height using Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same problem with 2010 report viewer today. This seems to work well...

```
  <style type="text/css">
        .fixScrollBarBug div div
        {
            overflow: visible;
        }

        .fixScrollBarBug div div div
        {
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>

<rsweb:reportviewer ID="reportMonthlyReport" runat="server" ProcessingMode="Remote"
      CssClass="fixScrollBarBug"  AsyncRendering="false" SizeToReportContent="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is supposedly solved with the ReportViewer bundled with Visual Studio 2010 beta 2:

http://blogs.msdn.com/brianhartman/archive/2010/01/21/asyncrendering-and-all-the-baggage-that-comes-with-it.aspx

That said, I tried swapping out to the new version and just encountered a huge number of new, exciting, and different cross-browser issues. It may work well enough for what you're trying to do though.